# When using setHandler in ExtJS button, the handler function was executed right away

Tags: javascript, button, extjs

I added a button to a panel. When you click the button, a popup window will show up. I tried to update the content of the popup using setHandler. But whenever setHandler was called, the handler function was executed right away. Here is the example code:

```
    me.panels[i].getDockedItems()[0].setHandler(Popup({html: tiphtml}), this);
    ...
    Popup = function(cfg) {
      cfg = Ext.apply({
        height: 100, 
        width: 200,
        layout: 'fit'
      }, cfg);

      Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
          title: cfg.title,
          height: cfg.height,
          width: cfg.width,
          layout: cfg.layout,
          html: cfg.html 
      }).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to nest your function in an anonymous function.  You are actually calling the function in your code, not passing it.  This will work:

```
    me.panels[i].getDockedItems()[0].setHandler(function(){Popup({html: tiphtml})}, this);
    ...
    Popup = function(cfg) {
      cfg = Ext.apply({
        height: 100, 
        width: 200,
        layout: 'fit'
      }, cfg);

      Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
          title: cfg.title,
          height: cfg.height,
          width: cfg.width,
          layout: cfg.layout,
          html: cfg.html 
      }).show();
    }
```